# Area of a hexagon (that made of three triangles)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I want to find area of the hexagon that is in picture 
[image]
But I can't find area of two triangles that I marked with question mark . Would you please help me or give an Idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint:

Areas of four triangles they are equal to $6$.

Finally, for the hexagon area we obtain:
$$4\cdot6+3^2+4^2+5^2=74.$$

Comment: :I am thankful of your nice answer,but Why they are equal ?

Comment: Because $S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\gamma$ and $\sin(180^{\circ}-\gamma)=\sin\gamma.$

Comment: :OH thanks again,I got the point.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use trogonometry on the central triangle to find the obtuse angle of each marked triangle. Then I'd use the law of the cosine to find the third side. Then Heron's formula to find the area.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\left(2a+b\right)\left(a+2b\right)-6\cdot \frac12 a b \qquad\to\qquad 2\left(\,a^2+ab+b^2\,\right)$$

Comment: An alternate proof appears in the edit history. The one above doesn't make an unnecessary appeal to the Pythagorean theorem.